# how to manage credential in jenkins with ldap domain

Tags: security, jenkins, ldap, credentials

Within a jenkins pipeline I use username and password in plain text several times.
I know that through the cedential plugin I can hide the password, but my problem is that the jenkins server and all the software devops are on an LDAP managed domain.
For security issues the user password is changed every 30 days and I have the problem of updating the password within the pipeline.
I would like that every time I change the password I don't have to remodify the pipeline, probably the credential plugin can handle this but I don't know how to do it.
What is the correct way to handle this? not being an expert in jenkins I would be grateful if someone could give me detailed directions.